# django html video tag

Tags: html, django, video, tags

I'm trying to do a project in django.
I created the HTML-CSS page. I'm playing a video in the background of my HTML page. When I run this on local, I can see the video playing in the background.
But when I add my HTML page's codes to django it doesn't show up.
My video tag in html code(source part) like this;

```
src="homevideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"
```

IN DJANGO;
project name : lubdub
appname : accounts

views.py

```
def home(request):
    return render(request,'accounts/home.html')
```

setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), )


templates
    videos
        homevideo.mp4
```

Would anyone help me plase? I'm so confused.Thx

Answer (score 0):

The video is on your local machine so:-

#FIRST YOU HAVE TO SET YOUR DIRECTORY STRUCTURE #

MORE ON:- [DJANGO DOCUMENTATION](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/)

on top of your HTML page

```
{% load static %}
```

and then

```
src="{% static="PATH/TO/STATIC/DIR/homevideo.mp4"%}"
```

I will prefer to upload it on Youtube or somewhere else so if my servers are slow it will not affect Users experience

Comment: Sir, I add already ;
{% load static %}  top of html page.

And, I added my setting.py;
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

and;
src="{% static="videos/homevideo.mp4"%} I added like this.
But don't work.The video which is background.. the video's time approximately 10s And I was add it background- it is look like raining snow-like a animation. So, I do not upload on some videoplatform.

Comment: Frankly, I don't know how all the code is added to stockowerflow.Can I do it like this? What if I take a video of my codes, add it to youtube and deliver it to you? Sir?

Comment: you can mail me:- contact@princerawat.ml

Comment: OMG SİR... I DO İT NOW :) I 'm so happy OMG...yuppii